# Adding seconds to timestamp in a defined interval in R

Tags: r

I've a dataset with ID and timestamp.

Each ID mostly has 12 observations of time stamp for each minute.
I 'm having a hard time adding 5 seconds interval to each timestamp for each minute.

```
Actual Data                     Desired Format

    ID       Time           ID        Time     
    4466    12/1/14 19:56   4466    12/1/14 19:56:00
    4466    12/1/14 19:56   4466    12/1/14 19:56:05
    4466    12/1/14 19:56   4466    12/1/14 19:56:10
    4466    12/1/14 19:56   4466    12/1/14 19:56:15
    4466    12/1/14 19:56   4466    12/1/14 19:56:20
    4466    12/1/14 19:56   4466    12/1/14 19:56:25
    4466    12/1/14 19:56   4466    12/1/14 19:56:30
    4466    12/1/14 19:56   4466    12/1/14 19:56:35
    4466    12/1/14 19:56   4466    12/1/14 19:56:40
    4466    12/1/14 19:56   4466    12/1/14 19:56:45
    4466    12/1/14 19:56   4466    12/1/14 19:56:50
    4466    12/1/14 19:56   4466    12/1/14 19:56:55
    1136    3/23/15 23:00   1136    3/23/15 23:00:00
    1136    3/23/15 23:00   1136    3/23/15 23:00:05
    1136    3/23/15 23:00   1136    3/23/15 23:00:10
    1136    3/23/15 23:01   1136    3/23/15 23:01:00
    1136    3/23/15 23:01   1136    3/23/15 23:01:05
    1136    3/23/15 23:01   1136    3/23/15 23:01:10
    1136    3/23/15 23:01   1136    3/23/15 23:01:15
    1136    3/23/15 23:01   1136    3/23/15 23:01:20
    1136    3/23/15 23:01   1136    3/23/15 23:01:25
    1136    3/23/15 23:01   1136    3/23/15 23:01:30
    1136    3/23/15 23:01   1136    3/23/15 23:01:35
    1136    3/23/15 23:01   1136    3/23/15 23:01:40
    1136    3/23/15 23:01   1136    3/23/15 23:01:45
    1136    3/23/15 23:01   1136    3/23/15 23:01:50
    1136    3/23/15 23:01   1136    3/23/15 23:01:55
```

Comment: I'd start by converting your data to an actual `POSIXct` datetime object first - `dat$Time <- as.POSIXct(dat$Time, format="%m/%d/%y %H:%M", tz="UTC")` - working with dates as text is just waiting for errors.

Answer (score 1):

We can do this with `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`), grouped by 'ID' and 'Time', paste the 'Time' with sequence created for every 5 seconds using `sprintf` to create 'NewTime' column

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, NewTime := sprintf("%s:%02d", Time, 
          seq(0, 55, by = 5)[seq_len(.N)]) , .(ID, Time)]
df1
#      ID          Time          NewTime
# 1: 4466 12/1/14 19:56 12/1/14 19:56:00
# 2: 4466 12/1/14 19:56 12/1/14 19:56:05
# 3: 4466 12/1/14 19:56 12/1/14 19:56:10
# 4: 4466 12/1/14 19:56 12/1/14 19:56:15
# 5: 4466 12/1/14 19:56 12/1/14 19:56:20
# 6: 4466 12/1/14 19:56 12/1/14 19:56:25
# 7: 4466 12/1/14 19:56 12/1/14 19:56:30
# 8: 4466 12/1/14 19:56 12/1/14 19:56:35
# 9: 4466 12/1/14 19:56 12/1/14 19:56:40
#10: 4466 12/1/14 19:56 12/1/14 19:56:45
#11: 4466 12/1/14 19:56 12/1/14 19:56:50
#12: 4466 12/1/14 19:56 12/1/14 19:56:55
#13: 1136 3/23/15 23:00 3/23/15 23:00:00
#14: 1136 3/23/15 23:00 3/23/15 23:00:05
#15: 1136 3/23/15 23:00 3/23/15 23:00:10
#16: 1136 3/23/15 23:01 3/23/15 23:01:00
#17: 1136 3/23/15 23:01 3/23/15 23:01:05
#18: 1136 3/23/15 23:01 3/23/15 23:01:10
#19: 1136 3/23/15 23:01 3/23/15 23:01:15
#20: 1136 3/23/15 23:01 3/23/15 23:01:20
#21: 1136 3/23/15 23:01 3/23/15 23:01:25
#22: 1136 3/23/15 23:01 3/23/15 23:01:30
#23: 1136 3/23/15 23:01 3/23/15 23:01:35
#24: 1136 3/23/15 23:01 3/23/15 23:01:40
#25: 1136 3/23/15 23:01 3/23/15 23:01:45
#26: 1136 3/23/15 23:01 3/23/15 23:01:50
#27: 1136 3/23/15 23:01 3/23/15 23:01:55
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = c(4466L, 4466L, 4466L, 4466L, 4466L, 4466L, 
4466L, 4466L, 4466L, 4466L, 4466L, 4466L, 1136L, 1136L, 1136L, 
1136L, 1136L, 1136L, 1136L, 1136L, 1136L, 1136L, 1136L, 1136L, 
1136L, 1136L, 1136L), Time = c("12/1/14 19:56", "12/1/14 19:56", 
"12/1/14 19:56", "12/1/14 19:56", "12/1/14 19:56", "12/1/14 19:56", 
"12/1/14 19:56", "12/1/14 19:56", "12/1/14 19:56", "12/1/14 19:56", 
"12/1/14 19:56", "12/1/14 19:56", "3/23/15 23:00", "3/23/15 23:00", 
"3/23/15 23:00", "3/23/15 23:01", "3/23/15 23:01", "3/23/15 23:01", 
"3/23/15 23:01", "3/23/15 23:01", "3/23/15 23:01", "3/23/15 23:01", 
"3/23/15 23:01", "3/23/15 23:01", "3/23/15 23:01", "3/23/15 23:01", 
"3/23/15 23:01")), .Names = c("ID", "Time"), row.names = c(NA, 
-27L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `group_by()` and `row_number()` from package `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(ID,Time ) %>%
  mutate(NTime=sprintf("%s.%02d",Time, row_number(Time)*5))
```

Answer (score 0):

Or just:

```
df <- data.frame(ID = 4466, Time = "12/1/14 19:56") 
df2 <- cbind(df[rep(1 : nrow(df),each=12),], ntime = strptime (paste(df$Time, ":", seq(0, 55, 5),sep=""), "%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S", tz= "UTC"))
```